# Can't connect to CloudSQL (using GAE + Django)

Tags: python, mysql, django, sockets, google-app-engine

### The Problem

I am unable to connect to CloudSQL via Django in Google App Engine (flexible) on the production server. I am using Python 3 if that makes a difference.

I'm using this example in my **settings.py**:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'HOST': '/cloudsql/<your-project-id>:<your-cloud-sql-instance>',
        'NAME': '<your-database-name>',
        'USER': 'root',
    }
}
```

(With the IDs filled in, of course.)

When I used the socket, I was unable to connect at all:
**Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/cloudsql/projectid:cloudsqlid' (2)**

When I tried using IPv4 instead of socket, I was able to connect to the database, but then I get this error:
**Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet'**

Even stranger, when I tried connecting to CloudSQL on my local server (using IPv4 of course), I was able to connect just fine. It's only the deployed app that is giving me trouble.

Here's my **app.yaml**

```
runtime: python
threadsafe: true
vm: true
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT myapp.wsgi:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3
```

### Confusion

It says `<your-cloud-sql-instance>`, which I'm assuming means the ID of the SQL instance. But I also noticed on the "Overview" for the SQL instance, it says `Instance connection name: projectid:us-central1:cloudsqlid`. I tried using this connection name in place of the `<your-project-id>:<your-cloud-sql-instance>` with no luck.

Here's a quote from the Google App Engine docs specific to CloudSQL and Django:
`The Google Cloud SQL instance to which you're connecting, in the format '/cloudsql/your-project-id:your-instance-name' or '/cloudsql/domain:your-project-id:your-instance_name'.`

Here it says there are two ways of connecting via socket (Why? I'm not sure), but adding "domain:" doesn't seem to help anything either.

I can't say for sure that I tried every combination of the variations above, so it's possible that I missed something.

I would prefer to connect via socket, not IPv4.

Comment: Did you add the `beta_settings: cloud_sql_instances:` part to your app.yaml ? I am fighting with the same problem, did you sort it out?

Comment: Sorry, this was 5 months ago. Since then ive converted all of my code to use the Datastore only. Good luck! (and no I did not try adding beta_settings to my app.yaml)

Comment: damn i am stuck with this too, so freaking unclear google docs!!

Comment: @Manza enable the private IP on cloudsql instance from connection tab